# How can I undo multiple git commits?

Tags: git, github, gitlab

Is there anyway to delete/undo like the last 5 commits? I have an issue that is too muddled up to fix so I would rather go back to a commit that i know is stable

Answer (score 2):

Issue this command:

```sh
git reset --soft HEAD~6
```

If you want to loose changes:

```sh
git reset --hard HEAD~6
```

Comment: what is HEAD~6 ?

Comment: `HEAD` is a pointer to your top commt. By `HEAD~6` we are telling to **git** to reference back to 6 commits as last good commit.

Comment: Ah i see, thank you!

Comment: Please accept my solution if you think it is correct.

Comment: I can only do so in 9 minutes, I'll do so then!

Comment: When I do this, and want to push a new change, it tells me I must pull the commits i undid again

Comment: That means that you have commits not yet pushed. Try `git stash save && git pull && git stash pop`.

Comment: That brought me back to square one unfortunately

Comment: Now you are addressing a different issue from your original post. I suggest you to open a new one with all the details and issued commands.

Comment: _When I do this, and want to push a new change, it tells me I must pull the commits i undid again_ I'd actually say this sounds like you've already pushed some of the changes you rolled back to the remote already.  You _may_ need to force push, but make _sure_ you know what you're doing because you'll be irreversibly destroying history.